# Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'purchased1_.DTYPE' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi i am facing some problem while i am trying to get the data my schema defined is as below

purchased.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="purchased_listing")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="purchased")
public abstract class Purchased extends BaseDo implements Reportable {
     public Purchased() {
    super();
}
    //some implementation
}
```

reportable.java

```
public interface Reportable {

}
```

and i have another class appointment.java like and i am mapping purchased with many to one mapping like below

appointment.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="appointments")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="class_code")
@DiscriminatorValue("appointment")
public class Appointment extends BaseDo implements Delivery {
        public Appointment() {

    }

        @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="purchased_id")
    private Purchased purchased;

}
```

and interface delivery.java which appointment is implemented is like

```
public interface Delivery {

    public long getId();

    public DeliveryStatus getDeliveryStatus();

}
```

now actually when iam trying to query like

```
public Appointment getAppointmentInfoByAppointmentId(long id) throws DaoException {
    Iterator<Appointment> itr = getHibernateTemplate().iterate(
            "from Appointment app where app.id = ?", id);
    if (itr.hasNext()) {
        return itr.next();
    }
    throw new DaoException("No appointment found with id = " + id);
}
```

and when iam trying to inspect the return appointment object Iam getting like **objectinvocation exception** and in my code when iam trying to to like

appointment.getId();

Iam getting error like

**Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'purchased1_.DTYPE' in 'field list'**

Struggling for this since one day couldn't get the solution so why iam facing this porblem and how to resolve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed `@DiscriminatorColumn` in purchased.java

Comment: works like charm really appreciable i don't understand how i missed that anyway your answer resolved my problem thanks a lot accepting your answer